# Text Selection for whole element except one child

Tags: javascript

I have code like this:

```
function select_all(element) {
    var range;
    if (document.body.createTextRange) {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(element);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        if (selection.setBaseAndExtent) {
            selection.setBaseAndExtent(element, 0, element, 1);
        } else if (document.createRange) {
            range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(element);
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(range);
        }
    }
}
```

it work fine, except one thing, I have html like this:

```
<div class="root">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="output" role="log">
      <div>text</div>
      <!-- there can be more divs here -->
    </div>
    <div class="inner" style="width: 100%;">
      <span class="foo" style="visibility: visible;">
        <span>&gt;&nbsp;</span>
      </span>
      <div class="cursor-line" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true">
        <span></span>
        <span class="cursor">&nbsp;</span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
      <!-- there can be more divs here -->
      <textarea autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" tabindex="1" class="clipboard" style=""></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and when I call that function textarea gets also selected, I've try to clear selection in textarea but it seems that there is only one selection and it dissapear.

I've also try to remove textarea before selection and append after but this also make textarea selected.

How can I select root except textarea?

I can't move textarea outside because to need to be relative to `.inner`

Comment: *And we're back in the early 2000's :)* What browsers do you need to serve? Imo `createRange` is the most flexible approach, with its possibility to `set Start/End Before/After (node)`, and according to MDN it is supported from everything IE9 upwards. *Although I have a problem when trying to implement that and answer; seems not to select ranges where the start is more nested than the end.*

Comment: @Thomas I've used range object setStart on `.output` and setEnd on last div in `.inner` and it work. Thanks. I've also keep setBaseAndExtent the code is for Safari don't know if they changed the api.